# ListView that have its .itemssource set to a list but doesn't update when I add item to the list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

It sounds quite simple, but actually took me several hours and still not done.
Here is my C# code:

```
    public ItemEditor() {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListView_Item.ItemsSource = TestList;
    }

    List<Item> TestList = new List<Item>();

    private void MenuItem_AddNewItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Item newItem = new Item();
        TestList.Add(newItem);
        newItem.Name = "new item";
    }
```

When function MenuItem_AddNewItem_Click is executed, the listview never update. I cannot figure out how can it be like this.
And here is my xaml code:

```
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView_Item" Grid.Column="0" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenu_ListView_Item}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="5"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock>Name:</TextBlock>
                <TextBox></TextBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2"></Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Can any one help me? I have looked at many webpages, there were similar situations, but non of them can help me solve my problem.

Comment: Use observablecollection instead of List. Check this out [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection)

Comment: @neelesh bodgal I tried, it still dosen't work

Comment: Please provide the updated code. ObservableCollection or any other source supporting INotifyCollectionChanged should provide this functionality.

Comment: I tested your code, when u replace with list with observablecollection it works. Share your updated code. You can verify whether command bindings to menu is proper and MenuItem_AddNewItem_Click is called.

Comment: @neelesh okay, I just got it done, thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, using an ObservableCollection is the simplest way to achieve this. It's what that collection is designed for. If you ever need to modify an existing custom collection type rather than using ObservableCollection you'd want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged.